# What is the time complexity of a comparison or substitution operation?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

When estimating the time complexity of a certain algorithm, let's say the following in pseudo code:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) ---> O(n)
  //comparison? ---> ?
  //substitution ---> ?
 for (int i=0; i<n; i++) ---> O(n)
  //some function which is not recursive
```

In this case the time complexity of these instructions is `O(n)` because we iterate over the input `n`, but how about the comparison and substitution operations are they constant time since they don't depend on `n`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, read [this](http://kddlab.zjgsu.edu.cn:7200/students/lipengcheng/%E7%AE%97%E6%B3%95%E5%AF%BC%E8%AE%BA%EF%BC%88%E8%8B%B1%E6%96%87%E7%AC%AC%E4%B8%89%E7%89%88%EF%BC%89.pdf) book. Here is good explanation of this topic.

1. Comparsion. For instance, we have two variables **a** and **b**. And when we doing this `a==b`we just take **a** and **b** from the memory and compare them. Let's define "*c*" as cost of memory, and "*t*" as cost of time. In this case we're using *2c* (because we're using two cells of the memory) and *1t* (because there is only one operation with the constant cost), therefore the *1t* - is the constan. Thus the time complexity is constant.
2. Substitution. It's pretty same as the previous operation. We're using two variables and one operation. This operation is same for the any type, therefore the cost of the time of the substitutin is constant. Then complexity is constant too.

Answer (score 5):

Both of the other answers assume you are comparing some sort of fixed-size data type, such as 32-bit integers, doubles, or characters. If you are using operators like `<` in a language such as Java where they can only be used on fixed-size data types, and cannot be overloaded, then that is correct. But your question is not language-specific, and you also did not say you are comparing using such operators.

In general, the time complexity of a comparison operation depends on the data type you are comparing. It takes O(1) time to compare 64-bit integers, doubles, or characters, for example. But as a counter-example comparing strings in lexicographic order takes O(min(*k*, *k'*)) time in the worst case, where *k*, *k'* are the lengths of the strings.

For example, here is the Java source code for the [`String.compareTo`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) method in OpenJDK 7, which clearly does not take constant time:

```java
    public int compareTo(String anotherString) {
        int len1 = value.length;
        int len2 = anotherString.value.length;
        int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);
        char v1[] = value;
        char v2[] = anotherString.value;

        int k = 0;
        while (k < lim) {
            char c1 = v1[k];
            char c2 = v2[k];
            if (c1 != c2) {
                return c1 - c2;
            }
            k++;
        }
        return len1 - len2;
    }
```

Therefore when analysing the time complexity of comparison-based sorting algorithms, we often analyse their complexity *in terms of* the number of comparisons and substitutions, rather than the number of basic operations; for example, [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) does O(*n*) substitutions and O(*n*²) comparisons, whereas [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) does O(*n* log *n*) substitutions and O(*n* log *n*) comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

> but how about the comparison and substitution operations are they
>   constant time since they don't depend on n?

**Yes**. Comparison and substitution operations are a constant factor because their execution time doesn't depend on a size of the input. Their execution time takes time but, again, it's independent from the input size.

However, the execution time of your `for` loop grows proportionally to the number of items `n` and so its time complexity is `O(n)`.

**UPDATE**

As @kaya3 correctly pointed out, we assume that we deal with fixed-size data types. If they're not then check an answer from @kaya3.